# How to get the entire response body in Loadrunner VUGen?

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

I need to get entire response body in Loadrunner VUGen. I try

```
web_set_max_html_param_len("60000");
web_reg_save_param_ex(
    "ParamName=js_top",
    "LB=",
    "RB=",
    SEARCH_FILTERS,
    "Scope=Body",
    LAST);
web_url("categories",
        "URL=https://advantageonlineshopping.com/catalog/api/v1/categories", 
        "TargetFrame=", 
        "Resource=0", 
        "RecContentType=application/json", 
        "Referer=https://advantageonlineshopping.com/", 
        "Snapshot=t20.inf", 
        "Mode=HTML", 
        LAST);
```

but get an error:
Action.c(147): Error -26377: No match found for the requested parameter "js_top". Either the specified boundaries were not found in the response or the matched text is longer than current max html parameter size of 60000 bytes. The total length of the response is 4477 bytes. You can use "web_set_max_html_param_len" to increase the max parameter size.    [MsgId: MERR-26377]

Comment: "LB=<html","RB=</html>"

Answer (score 1):

try using below and let me know if you face any issue.

```
web_set_max_html_param_len("9999999");
web_reg_save_param("c_fullresponse", "LB=", "RB=", LAST);
web_url("categories",
        "URL=https://advantageonlineshopping.com/catalog/api/v1/categories", 
        "TargetFrame=", 
        "Resource=0", 
        "RecContentType=application/json", 
        "Referer=https://advantageonlineshopping.com/", 
        "Snapshot=t20.inf", 
        "Mode=HTML", 
        LAST);
```

If you still get an error, try enabling Log. Turn on Server Trace, from Logs in runtime settings.
You will get the response after enabling log. From that data, you can decide what LB or RB you need, to capture the complete response.

Comment: Above  code and solution is working for me

Answer (score 0):

That code works for me:

```
    web_set_max_html_param_len("9999999");
        web_reg_save_param_json(
            "ParamName=userId", // Specify the parameter name to store the captured value
            "QueryString=$.data.accessToken", // Specify the JSONPath expression to extract the value
            //"Ordinal=1", // Specify the occurrence of the value if there are multiple matches
            LAST); 

web_custom_request("login_2", 
        "URL=https://reconstream-int.timestreamgroup.com/api/users/login", 
        "Method=POST", 
        "Resource=0", 
        "RecContentType=application/json", 
        "Referer=https://reconstream-int.timestreamgroup.com/login", 
        "Snapshot=t334.inf", 
        "Mode=HTML", 
        "EncType=application/json", 
        "Body={\"data\":{\"username\":\"ch.mudassar.@gmail.com\",\"password\":\"@2023\"}}", 
        LAST);
        
        web_set_user("reconstream-int.timestreamgroup.com\\ch.mudassar@gmail.com", "@2023", "reconstream-int.timestreamgroup.com");
        lr_think_time(60);
        /*web_reg_save_param("data",
        "LB/IC={\"data\": {",
        "RB/IC=\"checker\": null}",
        LAST);*/
        //lr_output_message("Response Body: %s", lr_eval_string("{data}"));
    
        
        lr_output_message("Response Body: %s", lr_eval_string("{userId}"));
```